# Setting a local array to its value

Tags: bash, shell

I have these two functions:

```
function two() {
  local -a -x var=( ${var[@]} )
  echo "${var[@]}"
}
function one() {
  local -a -x var=(11 22 33)
  two
}
```

If I call one, then nothing is printed. Why is that?

Comment: BTW, `${var[@]}` is different from `"${var[@]}"` -- the former will string-split and glob-expand your contents, so you can get an array with very different values from the one you think you're copying.

Comment: (As another aside -- `function foo() {` is a hybrid of POSIX and legacy ksh syntax, yet is compatible with neither POSIX sh nor legacy ksh. Consider either writing a POSIX function declaration as `foo() {` without any preceding `function`, or a `ksh` one as `function foo {` without any `()` -- though note that the semantics of this *do not* match behavior of the same syntax on ksh, where it will make variables local by default; see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> nothing is print. Why is that?

Here you're having the same identifier name `var` in both the functions
The `var` you defined in `one` could accessed by `two` because `two` is called from `one`. However,

> when declaring and setting a local variable in a single command,
>   apparently the order of operations is to first set the variable, and
>   only afterwards restrict it to local scope.

So in

```
 local -a -x var=( "${var[@]}" )
```

the `${var[@]}` part will be empty as the variable `var` is set local first.

To verify this you could change the variable name in `one` to `var1` and and in `two` do

```
local -a -x var=( "${var1[@]}" ) # var1 though local to one should be accessible here.
```

You could use @inian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525551/1620779) as a work-around to pass variables easily and yet not bother about such dark corners in bash.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not reflecting what are you trying to do! The locals you've defined are *only* within the scope of the function Yes! but if you are passing it to the other function, pass it as positional arguments `"$@"`. In the function below when you do `two "${var[@]}"`, you are passing the local array as a positional argument array to be used in the other function.

```
two() {
  local -a -x var=( "$@" )
  echo "${var[@]}"
}
```

The argument list `"$@"` represents the argument list passed to the function `two`, now from the function `one` pass it as

```
one() {
  local -a -x var=(11 22 33)
  two "${var[@]}"
}
```

Also the use of `function` keyword is non-standard. POSIX does not recommend using it. If you are planning to re-use script for multiple shells, drop the keyword. Also quote the variables/array to avoid them being string-splited and glob-expanded. It could result in unexpected values in the final array.

Also worth noting that variables/arrays are global by default unless you override with `local` keyword inside a function.

```
$ x=2
$ test_local(){ local x=1; }
$ test_local; echo "$x"
2
```

But the same without `local` would print the value as `1` which proves the point explained above.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `var` in `two` that declaration hides the one in `one`. Curiously, **local variables are visible in called functions**. The easiest way to make this work is to do nothing: simply access `$var` in `two`.

```
two() {
  echo "${var[@]}"
}

one() {
  local var=(11 22 33)
  two "${var[@]}"
}
```

I don't necessarily recommend doing this, though. It makes it hard to understand what `two` does just by reading it. It's better to explicitly pass the values as arguments.

```
two() {
  local var=("$@")
  echo "${var[@]}"
}

one() {
  local var=(11 22 33)
  two "${var[@]}"
}
```

---

By the way, you should always quote your variable expansions to prevent them from being subjected to word splitting and globbing. In your original code you should quote `${var[@]}`:

```
local -a -x var=( "${var[@]}" )
```

Also, for portability you should either write `one()` or `function one`, but not both. I prefer the former.